# Turning off consistency check on Microsoft SQL script restore

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, consistency

On several other databases I've come across, one can turn off the consistency check when restoring a (scripted) dump of the database. The idea is that when you have dumped the script from a database, you can restore it safely, without doing consistency checks, both to speed things up, and to not be hindered by the *order* which you stash in the different tables, foreign keys, views etc.

(On Microsoft SQL (2005) you have the 'generate and publish scripts'.)

Is there such a switch for MS SQL? And obviously, how do you turn it on again - and how can you potentially force a global consistency check afterwards?

PS: I do not necessarily need this feature to execute scripts which the server has produced..!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont think it can be donne, but Im not sure.

What can be donne is manually disable the constraint with the code:

```
ALTER TABLE table_name 
NOCHECK CONSTRAINT constraint_name
```

and enable it using the same syntax, just change NOCHECK to CHECK

If you really need it to the whole DB you can easly build something to loop through the tables and constraints and execute this  code

Comment: Thanks! Here's a googled link about this: http://odetocode.com/Articles/79.aspx. To do check of the constraints after you've re-enabled them, do 'dbcc checkconstraints([tablename|database])'.

Answer (score 1):

The "generate scripts" option (2005) for a given database produces the code required to create the database objects only. It does not script out the table contents (as per MySQL for example) and hence no need for an option to disable constraint checking.

If you wish to restore a copy of a database and it's data then the preferable route is to perform a Database Backup, followed by a database Restore.

There are some third party backup products that will enable you to restore specific objects only, from a Full database backup.

Comment: But you will have to do it in correct order, right? Can you create a view or e.g. a foreign key without the target table? Certain database setups call for cycles - which must be handled very delicately if there is constraints-checking upon "restore". PS: I don't necessarily want this feature to execute scripts which the server has created..!

Comment: I believe that there is a Script option to include dependant objects. This is to ensure that all required objects and their ordering is accounted for.

Comment: You cannot create a constraint or view on a database object that does not exist.

Comment: A database restore does not perform constraint checking. The database data pages themselves are restored from backup. Consider that the constraint checking would have already been passed at source prior to the database backup and so there is no need to re-perform it as part of a restore operation.

Comment: I am asking about the "restore" operation of the generated scripts, i.e. execute the SQL file. I do not here care about the actual backup/restore functions.